# Dragging map to the selected marker from the list line leaflet map

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, jquery-events, marker

If I am on the list of agencies, and each time I click on the agency line, it will slide on the map to marker.

In this case, it do jump not drag on the map:

```
$("#myTable tr").hover(function () {
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        $.get("../get_info.php", { id: id }, function (response) {
  
            var json = JSON.parse(response);
             mymap.panTo(new L.LatLng(json["lat"], json["lon"]));
             mymap.setZoom(15);
           
        });
    });
```

This code resolve my problem

```
map.flyTo([json["lat"], json["lon"]], 10, {
                animate: true,
                duration: 1.5
            });
```

But now , I want popup open automatically after zoom

Answer (score 1):

I had me situation in one of my projects and I do as below:

```
<script>
    var lat = 32.699852569257246;
    var lon = -72.337867895135915;
    var zoom = 4;
    var map;
    var markers = [];

    function addMarker(id, lat, lng, p) {
        var myLatLng = new L.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var marker = L.marker(myLatLng, { alt: id }).addTo(map).bindPopup(p);
        markers.push(marker);
    }

    function ShowOnMap(id) {
        for (var i in markers) {
            var markerID = markers[i].options.alt;
            if (markerID == id) {
                map.setView(markers[i].getLatLng(), 16);
                markers[i].openPopup();
            };
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Create Map
        map = L.map('map', {
            center: [lat, lon],
            zoom: zoom,
        });

        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);

        // Add marker of each Physician Department
        $('input[name=DepartmentPhysicianId]', '#steps-uid').each(function () {
            addMarker($(this).val(), $(this).data('lat'), $(this).data('lon'), $(this).data('description'));
        });

        // Show popup when user click on each Physician Department
        $('input[name=DepartmentPhysicianId]', '#steps-uid').on('change', function () {
            ShowOnMap($(this).val());
        });

        var group = new L.featureGroup(markers);
        map.fitBounds(group.getBounds(), { padding: [50, 50] });
    });

</script>
```